# How to perform a button click after a postback to open a modal window

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with making my button perform a click after a postback. I am validating some textboxes within a modal window on a web page, which only appears after a button click. Currently after the postback the web page re-opens and the modal window is closed, which is required to be open. There is no handler in my code, the button is clicked and runs html code to bring up the modal window. I need this button to perform a click once i have posted back so that the validation is initiated. I have tried using btnSickness.Click() but it does not seem to like this and can't seem to find anything anywhere!  Code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    int i = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i > 0)
           {
           }      

    }

    protected void chkDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (drpDoctor.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        {
            txtIfNoWhy.ReadOnly = true;
            txtIfNoWhy.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            i++;
        }
        else if (drpDoctor.SelectedValue == "No")
        {
            txtDocName.ReadOnly = true;
            txtHouseName.ReadOnly = true;
            txtStreet.ReadOnly = true;
            txtTownCity.ReadOnly = true;
            txtCounty.ReadOnly = true;
            txtPostalcode.ReadOnly = true;
            txtInitialDate.ReadOnly = true;
            txtTreatmentRecieved.ReadOnly = true;
            txtCurrentTreatment.ReadOnly = true;

            txtDocName.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtHouseName.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtStreet.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtTownCity.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtCounty.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtPostalcode.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtInitialDate.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtTreatmentRecieved.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            txtCurrentTreatment.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Modal window code:

```
<div class"modal" id="myModal"></div> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
                <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#Div1" ID="btnSickness" Text="Submit a Sickness Form" />
                       <div class="modal hide" id="Div1">
<div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3>Sickness Form</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Please fill in the following information regarding your sickness</p>
<br />
<p>Sickness Date From:</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSicknessFrom"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<p>Sickness Date To:</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSicknessTo"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
<p>Absence Date To:</p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAbsenceFrom"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: `if (i > 0)` => `i` is never != 0 due to the statelessness of http. Apart from that i don't understand the question. _"so that the validation is initiated"_ What validation? If you need to trigger validation on serverside call `Page.Validate()`.

Comment: The validation of making textboxes read only. But to do this, a postback is required

Comment: The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is a serverside event. It's never called without a postback and `i` is a variable that gets disposed as soon as the page is rendered, it won't survive a postback and always gets initiliazed with 0.

Comment: ok, i just need help with performing a click after a postback.

Comment: Is this modal shown via javascript?

Comment: A click-event(every event) is only triggered by the user, without exception. You should refactor your code and provide a method for the action you want to execute. Then you can call this method from wherever you want.

Comment: Yes it is not called within the code, as I am unable to see it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a hidden field to tell the modal to show when you return from the server. Then you can add a pageLoad javascript function, which runs every time the pageLoads, to check  if you need to show the modal.

**Serverside**:

```
hdf_ShowModal.Value = "true";
```

**HTML**:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_ShowModal" />
```

**Javascript**:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
    if(document.getElementById('<%= hdf_ShowModal.ClientID %>').value == "true")
    {
        // perform code to show modal
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Since you are using jquery as well, you can try the following to show the modal:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
    if($('[id$=hdf_ShowModal]').val() == "true")
        $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= hdf_ShowModal.ClientID %>').value == "true") {
            $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
        }
    }